# import module and boostraping app after promise response

Tags: angular, import, module

I have a promise which returns the configuration fields (instead of environment variables), and only after the response is received, the application is boostraped.

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {
    this.configService.init().then((config) => {
      app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that a module which is injected inside of `@NgModule()` have the configuration object as dependency. So, I need to import it only after service response (as in boostraping case).

```
@NgModule({

  imports: [
    ...,
    // configuration is load inside of class (below)
    StylesComponentsModule.forRoot(configuration) // in old implementation, here was used environment object
  ]
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

Is there a possibility to add the imported module inside of the `AppModule` class (as in boostraping example)? Something like ngDoImport not working ...

real problem: `StylesComponentsModule` is a internal library which require the environment variables from the parent app. Because we changed the environment file with a configuration json loaded at runtime, we need to provide this configuration object to the `StylesComponentsModule` after the response of `configService.init()` is received.

later edit:

this solution can works

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
    
  ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {
    this.configService.init().then((config) => {
      import('module/path')
        then(module => module.forRoot(config));
  
      app.bootstrap(AppComponent);
    });
  }
}
```

thx

Comment: If your app module is generated, then it means your app has already been bootstraped. If you want to wait for a config to be loaded, then you will need to edit your `main.ts` file in order to TRULY wait for the app to be bootstrapped.

Comment: I found that I can import the package directly inside of promise payload. But probably still should tell somehow that this package should be added inside of `imports` array

Comment: If you can use dependency injection, it means you app has an injector, which is what is created on bootstrapping. Your app is ALREADY EXISTING when you are running your code. Do you understand?

Comment: So, what you are telling me is that the application is bootstrapped before hitting the `ngDoBootstrap` method and waiting for the `Promise` result. So, the line `app.bootstrap(AppComponent)` is useless?! If yes, maybe I need to create the service first (in this way I can't use DI, and my service has as dependency the `HttpClient`), get the response, and only after that, to inject it inside of the module.

Comment: That's almost what I'm saying yes. Calling `app.bootstrap` RE-BOOTSTRAP your app, it does NOT bootstrap it after waiting for your HTTP call to end. And indeed, you would have to get all of your code outside of your services. Or, you can make an app initializer. I'm making an answer for that right now.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, this is not the right approach.

What should do instead is use the APP_INITIALIZER token :

[Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)

Or, if have routed components, you can also use resolvers when needed, so that you do not have to load your whole config everytime (improves the TTI, Time To Interactive, which is important)

Comment: I used this flow before changing to override `ngDoBootstrap` method, because I thought that using the second approach, it will wait for configuration before to be boostraped. The problem remain the same, I need to provide this configuration object to a module which is inside of `imports` array.

Comment: Sorry I thought the documentation was enough. [Here is a stackblitz to show you how to do it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gvysjk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts%3AL43,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Is that enough ?

Comment: I think you don't understand the real question of me :d  `imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule]`. let's say here, for `FormsModule`, I need to provide a configuration object: `FormsModule.forRoot(configuration)`. That is the problem, the configuration is served by the service, but how I can assign it to imported module? :D

Comment: You don't need to, that's the point. Your service contains your configuration. So inject your service into whatever module/component/service you need, and you can access your configuration. In simpler terms, the APP_INITIALIZER replaces the content of your `forRoot` function.

Comment: mh, it doesn't work. The external library complains about environment object not found (`NullInjectorError`, `no provider for environment`). I can understand why. Because my configuration object come from a service, and not from the `environment.ts` file, but probably should be explicitly added to this library.